# Java byte array to Javascript typed array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to send through Websocket binaryType protocol some raw data from Java Servlet to JavaScript
I read all about Byte Buffer, Typed Arrays and Data View on JavaScript but still I think I am missing the picture

My question is how do I convert an array of 8 bytes to a JavaScript Number?

I have the following byte array that should represent this double value
-1.4960627518157586E23

```
0 = -60
1 = -65
2 = -82
3 = 44
4 = 36
5 = 69
6 = -96
7 = 64
```

Can anybody help me in serializing byte data from Java to JavaScript types please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need it to be binary, was it too slow with JSON?

Comment: Can you show us you JS client side code?

Comment: I guess that if you used JSON format to send the data, you surely would save yourself the trouble of serializing and parsing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reading in Javascript

Reading binary data in Javascript takes some effort, but someone conveniently made a snippet of code which helps with that: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser

We can use it like so:

```
var parser = BinaryParser(true);
var outputVal = parser.toDouble([-60, -65, -82, 44, 36, 69, -96, 64]);
```

#### Reading in Java

In case you receive the data in java, you can use `java.io.DataInputStream` to read primitive values from a stream, like so:

```
byte[] dataArray = new byte[] {-60, -65, -82, 44, 36, 69, -96, 64};
DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataArray));

double val = stream.readDouble();
out.println(val); // -1.4960627518157586E23
```